Is it possible to use previously defined coordinates to be used within the tikzmath environment?
I want to utilize the tikzmath environment to perform some calculations on previously defined coordinates. For example, I have two coordinates P1 and P2. I wish to perform the following sample operations:

Define P1 and P2 using coordinate.
Calculate distance between P1 and P2 within tikzmath.
Divide the distance between P1 and P2 by a specified number within tikzmath.
Use the result after division from tikzmath calculations elsewhere.

Step 4 is understandable through plenty of examples and can be done. However, Step 2 and Step 3 is something which I am curious about.
This is the code which I was trying to make work(a sample):
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[intersections, calc, through, backgrounds, arrows.meta,math]
\usepackage{calculator}

% size of the text to be used in the figure
\newcommand {\FigText}[1]{ {\tiny #1} }


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

% example domain coefficients for figure drawing
\def \BCoeff{5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    
    %\clip (-6,-2) rectangle (6,0.5);
    
    % the grid
    %\draw[ultra thin] (-6,-2) grid (10,9);
    \tikzmath
    {
        % coordinate - origin
        coordinate \origin;
        \origin = (0,0);

        % coordinate - P1
        coordinate \P1;
        \P1 = (\origin) - (\BCoeff,0);
        {
            \fill [green] (\origin) circle (5pt);
            \path (\origin) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{Origin}};
            
            \fill [green] (\P1) circle (5pt);
            \path (\P1) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{P1}};
        };  
    }
    % the origin
    %\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

I have looked in the documentation specifically, Sec 58 titled "Math Library" but couldn't find anything. In general, can we refer to operations defined outside the tikzmath environment and perform further operations on them ?

Named coordinates are stored as global macros, so they will pass from a tikzpicture to tikzmath.  However, veclen(x,y) works on x and y values, which are normally local.  Easiest is just to use \pgfmathparse etc. inside a tikzpicture.  See also \pgfgetlastxy, \pgfpointdiff and \pgfpointanchor.

Can you give an example of using \pgfmathparse which takes a previously defined point ? I tried something like this \pgfmathsetmacro\WallLength{ $(P2) - (P1)$ }; and it gave me error.

BTW, I couldn't find a tikzmath environment, not even in CTAN.

One could create a pgfmath function that does this but the calc library allows let \p0=($(P1)-(P0)$), \n0={veclen(\x0,\y0)} in on a path and then \n0 will expand to the distance between the points in in canvas units. The same can be done with math but with different syntax, maybe coordinate \p; \p=($(P1)-(P0)$); real \n=veclen(\px,\py);. You probably need to use it as \n pt.

Here's an example where the veclen is tested against a fixed value: A652565. No $s are needed inside tikzmath, apparently.

I saw the three answers. In answer number 3, you have used curly braces to execute the drawing operation. I read about this in the documentation and tried it out. What I found out is that only one drawing operation can be executed. It can't take multiple drawing executions. Am I right in observing this ?

I added a small piece of code which I was playing around with.

I just posted an answer where I modified the original code and now it works.

I finally found \tikzmath (page 703), but it isn't an environment (no \endtikzmath).  No need to worry about local vs. global definitions.

Pgfmath doesn't work with named coordinates.  You need x and y values.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (P0) at (0,0);
\coordinate (P1) at (1,1);
\draw (P0) -- (P1);
% using calc
\path ($(P1)-(P0)$);% might affect bounding box, use pgfinterruptboundingbox if needed
\pgfgetlastxy{\X}{\Y}:% local macros
\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{veclen(\X, \Y)/1cm}]
\path (P0) -- (P1) node[midway, above, sloped] {\result};
% using \pgfpointdiff
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{P0}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{P1}{center}}
\pgfgetlastxy{\X}{\Y}:% local macros
\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{veclen(\X, \Y)/1cm}]
\path (P0) -- (P1) node[midway, below, sloped] {\result};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


This will work but I am wondering why can't we perform calculations within the tikzmath environment and refer them later. I mean, there is so much potential by parametrizing your coordinates and refer to them later. All kinds of stuff can be done within tikzmath based on the documentation. It supports a lot of mathematical functions as well.

I just posted an answer where I modified the original code and now it works.

While \tikzmath may not be an environment (in LaTeX nominclature), it might be a group.  You can use \global\let\foo=\foo to make \foo accessible outside \tikzmath, but you might want to reserve the g;obal name first (\newcommand{\foo}{}).

It looks like my original script was correct albeit, there shouldn't have been any empty lines after any of the commands. This is the working version:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[intersections, calc, through, backgrounds, arrows.meta,math]
\usepackage{calculator}

% size of the text to be used in the figure
\newcommand {\FigText}[1]{ {\tiny #1} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

% example domain coefficients for figure drawing
\def \BCoeff{5}
    \tikzmath
    {
        % coordinate - origin
        coordinate \origin = (0,0);
        \origin = (0,0);
        % coordinate - P1
        coordinate \P1;
        \P1 = (\origin) - (\BCoeff,0);
        {
            \fill [green] (\origin) circle (5pt);
            \path (\origin) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{Origin}};
            \fill [green] (\P1) circle (5pt);
            \path (\P1) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{P1}};
        };  
    }

    % outside tikzmath 
    \draw (\P1) -- (\origin);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

Two things I have found out that make it work:

The coordinate needs to defined and assigned separately. For example this will work:

coordinate \origin;
\origin = (0,0);

However, this will not work:
coordinate \origin = (0,0);


There should not be any empty lines(white spaces?) after your tikzmath-specific commands. However, the commands within braces {....}; will work with empty lines. For example this is ok:

    \tikzmath
    {
        % coordinate - origin
        coordinate \origin;
        \origin = (0,0);
        % coordinate - P1
        coordinate \P1;
        \P1 = (\origin) - (\BCoeff,0);
        {
            \fill [green] (\origin) circle (5pt);
            \path (\origin) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{Origin}};
            
            \fill [green] (\P1) circle (5pt);
            \path (\P1) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{P1}};
            
            \draw(\origin) -- ++(0,-\BCoeff);
        };  
    }

However, this is not ok( notice the empty line after the comment for point P1):
    \tikzmath
    {
        % coordinate - origin
        coordinate \origin;
        \origin = (0,0);
        % coordinate - P1

        coordinate \P1;
        \P1 = (\origin) - (\BCoeff,0);
        {
            \fill [green] (\origin) circle (5pt);
            \path (\origin) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{Origin}};
            
            \fill [green] (\P1) circle (5pt);
            \path (\P1) node[anchor=north] {\FigText{P1}};
            
            \draw(\origin) -- ++(0,-\BCoeff);
        };  
    }

I find these observations strange but it works. Someone more experienced can throw some light on this.
